# Assign any kind of protection to a custom menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If it is not possible , can i make any trick to open a msgbox then end the script if anyone try to access the script
Here is my code :

```
    function onOpen(){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('Private');
    menu.addItem('Clear Cols','clearAli');
    menu.addItem('Enter Number of days','noOfDays');
    menu.addItem('subject','myEmail')
    menu.addToUi();
    } 
 
    function clearAli(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ss.getRangeList(['G2:K108', 'M2:M108', 'O2:O108']).activate().clearContent();
    }
    function noOfDays(){
    var 
    days =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Please enter the number of days.').getResponseText();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('H2:H5').setValue(days);
    }
    function myEmail(){
    const 
subject = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter your subject line').getResponseText();GmailApp.sendEmail('noelaramouny@gmail.com,alinemanoukian04@gmail.com',subject,'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z92UC7RAqScObY2vpAKlzIvoY4yihxRtqw_2LEB2-8g/edit?usp=sharing');
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding your concern? Who is allowed to access the script and who is not allowed? You mean by anyone, including the owner of the file? Is your file shared to other user? Please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

```js
const whitelist = ['mail1', 'mail2'];
const user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
if (!whitelist.includes(user)) {
  Browser.msgBox('Not in whitelist');
  return;
}
```